# If $\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n} = 2$ where $a_n$ are positive integers, is there a subset such that $\sum_{n\in S} \frac{1}{a_n} = 1$?

Tags: summation, fractions, egyptian-fractions

As the title says: I'm wondering, out of curiosity, whether any (weak) Egyptian fraction decomposition of 2 always splits into two Egyptian fraction decompositions of 1.  By a "weak" Egyptian fraction decomposition, I mean one where the denominators are not necessarily required to be distinct.  (The problem with normal Egyptian fraction decompositions, where $a_n$ *are* required to be distinct, would also be interesting.)

In trying to construct a counterexample -- for example by taking enough prime numbers so that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} > 2$, removing the last one, and inserting enough remainder terms to make up the difference -- I run into a tension between having the denominators grow slowly enough for the sum to diverge, and on the other hand having the sum be close enough to 2 that the remainders can't bring the sums otherwise close to 1.  I haven't yet found a way for such an approach to work.

From the other end, I've written a simple Python script to try to search for decompositions of 2, and see for each whether it's splittable into 2 decompositions of 1.  At the current stage, I've been able to run it for lengths up to 7 and haven't found any counterexamples.  But when I try to allow length of 8, the run time (as the script stands) appears to be prohibitive; and if I trace through the decompositions of length 7 or less that it's testing, it appears that length 7 is not yet enough to get any really interesting decompositions.

Comment: Are the $a_n$s required to be distinct?

Comment: No, they don't have to be distinct.

Comment: When you write $\sum_{n}$, you mean $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ or $\sum_{k=0}^n$ ?

Comment: I meant a finite decomposition, $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{a_n}$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857872/if-sum-of-reciprocals-of-numbers-is-an-integer-then-there-exists-a-subset-with) where solutions with all denominators distinct were found  The largest denominator could be as small as $30030$

Comment: @RossMillikan OK, I agree this is a duplicate.  Should I jjust delete it, or should we vote to close?

Comment: @DanielSchepler:  I think just close it as a duplicate.  I started it.

Answer (score 5):

After making some optimizations to the Python script, I was eventually able to find a counterexample of length 8:
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{30} = 2.$$
To see this is a counterexample, suppose we had a splitting, and consider the part of the splitting that includes 30.  Then the sum of the reciprocals of the other elements must be $\frac{29}{30}$.  Therefore, that part of the splitting must also include at least one each of the 2, 3, 5 terms.  However, then already, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} > 1$, giving a contradiction.

If there are no bugs in the Python script, then it appears this is the unique counterexample of length 8 or less, up to permutation.

Comment: What if the $a_n$ are required to be distinct, as is usually required of Egyptian fractions?   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction and 
 https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html#:~:text=An%20Egyptian%20fraction%20is%20a,between%205%20and%20101. That is what I assumed was meant in the original question, which made it more interesting.

Comment: Hmm, if the $a_n$ were required to be distinct, then that would probably push it into the realm again where my Python script would be unworkable.

Comment: If uniqueness was required, one might find: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3597210?refreqid=excelsior%3A345b3a13637016edd76c6ff4779c8343&seq=1, to be relevant.

Comment: One potential way of doing it would be a greedy algorithm — start with some set of (probably relatively prime) numbers $\{p, q, r\}$, say, start with the sum $S= 1/p+1/q+1/r$, and at each stage choose the smallest $t$ such that $S+1/t\leq 2$ but none of the partial sums are equal to 1. This will get a little unmanageable as you get too many terms — since there are $2^n$ partial sums to be checked — but for $n$ in the range of 20-30 that's still very feasible, and several different $\{p,q,r\}$ sets could be tested to try and find examples.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a counterexample with $19$ terms: $2=\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}$ where

$$S=\{2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 30, 1547, 17017,
612612, 2450448\}$$

You can manually check that this sum is indeed $2$ but no subset of $S$ leads to a sum of $1$.

---

ADDENDUM: Since the answer is negative, this begets an interesting generalization: Let $r$ be a given positive rational and let $T$ be a finite set of rational numbers in $(0,r)$. Does there exist a finite set $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}=r$$

but

$$\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}\not\in T$$

for all $R\in P(S)$ (the powerset of $S$)? For example, in the original question $r=2$ and $T=\{1\}$. I would conjecture such an $S$ must exist for all $r$ and $T\subset (0,r)$ but I have no idea how one would even begin such a proof.